# Percentage values not formatting correctly in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a list of percentage values that are really small (0.000% format), this represents the error percentage of routers. i want to format the cell color depending on the amount on the cell. if the amount is more than 0.050% it should be Red, if it is more than 0.005% is amber, everything else is green

here is the code that i have written:

```
With .Cells(i, 8)
        If .NumberFormat <> "0.000%" Then
            .NumberFormat = "0.000%"
            If .Value2 <> vbNullString And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then .Value = .Value / 100
                If .Value2 = vbNullString Then
                    .Value = "---"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                End If
        Else
            .Value = 0
        End If

        If .Value > 0.05 Then
             .Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55) '<-- Red color
             .Font.Color = vbWhite

            ElseIf .Value > 0.005 Then
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0) '<-- Amber Colour
                .Font.Color = vbWhite

            Else
                .Interior.Color = RGB(50, 205, 50) '<-- Green color
                .Font.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    End With
```

but the colour format is not accurate, here is the list of some of the results:

```
0.034% <---green
0.845% <---amber
0.007% <---green
0.005% <---green
0.094% <---green
```

it should not be like that as the cell that contains 0.845% and is amber should be bright red!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value stored is not a percentage. It is the decimal equivalent, meaning you must shift the decimal point two places to the left. So to compare `0.05%` you must use `0.0005`.

Comment: @PaulOgilive i tried that yesterday and it did not work but i just tried again today and it did! cheers dude!

Answer (score 0):

This should clean up the code for you to make it a bit faster too:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Cel As Range, Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("H1:H" & Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each Cel In Rng
    If Trim(Cel.Value) = "" Then Cel.Value = "---": Cel.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    If IsNumeric(Cel.Value) Then
        Cel.Value = Cel.Value / 100
        If Cel.Value > 0.0005 Then
            Cel.Interior.Color = RGB(237, 67, 55): Cel.Font.Color = vbWhite
                ElseIf Cel.Value > 0.00005 Then
                    Cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0): Cel.Font.Color = vbWhite
                    Else: Cel.Interior.Color = RGB(50, 205, 50): Cel.Font.Color = vbWhite
        End If
    End If
Next

With Range("H1:H" & Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    .Value = "---"
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With

End Sub
```

I'm just after realizing Paul corrected your question....